# How to add graph to Leaflet popup using url.bindPopup

Tags: graph, popup, leaflet

I am trying to add a simple line graph into a leaflet popup when I select a polygon from a geoJson layer. 
Can I edit the url.bindPopup to achieve this? I would like to plot the 'poly_id' against the 'ha'. 
I hope someone is able to help me please. Here is my code I have been trying to edit but have been unsuccessful.

```
    var owsrootUrl = 'http://localhost:1997/geoserver/RSAC/wms';
    var defaultParameters = {
        service : 'WFS',
        version : '2.0',
        request : 'GetFeature',
        typeName : 'RSAC:results_clipped_with_growth_small',
        outputFormat : 'json',
        format_options : 'callback:getJson',
        SrsName : 'EPSG:4326'
    };

var parameters = L.Util.extend(defaultParameters);
var URL = owsrootUrl + L.Util.getParamString(parameters);
var ajax = $.ajax({
    url : URL,
    dataType : 'json',
    jsonpCallback : 'getJson',
    success : function (response) {
    L.geoJson(response, {
        onEachFeature: function (feature, url) {
            popupOptions = {maxWidth:250};
            url.bindPopup("<b>poly_id:</b>" + feature.properties.poly_id +
                "<br><b>ha: </b>" + feature.properties.ha + "<br><b>growth_new: </b>" + feature.properties.growth_new);
        }
                    }).addTo(mymap);
    }
});
```

Comment: Check [CanvasJS](https://canvasjs.com/html5-javascript-dynamic-chart/) and/or [Plot.ly](http://help.plot.ly/embed-graphs-in-websites/) to create the plots, then you can include this HTML code inside the popup tooltip.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have now created a chart in canvasjs and created a script called chart.js, is that correct or does it need to be in HTML? How do I then include the code inside the popup tool tip? This is the bit I'm unsure about.

Comment: I'd suggest to create the plot in plot.ly and then embeed the plot code with some additional options to the popup. Here's the [embeeding tutorial](https://help.plot.ly/embed-graphs-in-websites/) and here is a [live version](https://plnkr.co/edit/OBNR8k?p=preview) of  the example.